# hibernate error when using single table inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate

If I specify

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "tablename")
```

for the superclass, and

```
@Table(name = "tablename")
```

for the subclasses, hibernate throws an exception during application startup (only displaying final cause):

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Foreign key circularity dependency involving the following tables: 
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildRecursiveOrderedFkSecondPasses(Configuration.java:1570)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1511)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1420)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
... 98 more
```

As you can see in the above example, it does not say which tables are involved in the dependency circularity.

If anyone has any suggestions what may be the problem I would be very happy.

Comment: Have you defined discriminator properly?

Comment: It does not matter if I define it, the error does not change.

Comment: can you post your entity here?

Comment: I will try to simplify the entities so I can post them, this may take a while...

Comment: Thanks to @Madprogrammer's request, I tried to reproduce the problem in a small example, and managed to find the root. I post that below. If anyone is interested in the code itself, I can upload it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, I managed to find the problem. The problem is simple and straightforward, only the exception message was enormously unhelpful.

The root of the problem was that there was a superclass of the superclass (lets call it *baseclass*) that was explicitly specified as `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` as that was intended just as a common abstract class for many-many types of objects. It would, for example, specify a common `@Id` field, timestamps, whatnot.

It *had* to be marked as an `@Entity` as `@Id` declaration would not work otherwise (and would have to specify a `@Id` for each subclass of baseclass). The final solution seems to be that we have to do exactly that -- specify the id separately for each subclass of baseclass and maybe creating an intermediate class for non-singletable-inherited subclasses of baseclass to avoid lots of cloning.

**Update:**
The nice solution was to use `@MappedSuperclass`, so the superclass does not have to be an @Entity, but subclasses can inherit their fields and the fields' annotations, including @Id.